# Android - How to check the existence of a string value in another comma separated string

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist

Android - How to check the existence of a string value in another comma separated string .

```
 String all_vals  = "617,618,456,1,234,5,5678,225";
 String check_val= "456";
```

How to check like,

```
 if (all_vals contains check_val) { 

 }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Convert the comma-separated string to an array with `split`, then convert it to a `List` with `Arrays.asList`, then use `contains`.

```
String all_vals = "617,618,456,1,234,5,5678,225";
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(all_vals.split(","));
if (list.contains(check_val)) {

}
```

This will prevent the false positives from just checking if the substring exists in the list with `contains` directly on the string `all_vals`, e.g. `all_vals.contains("4")` would return `true` in the direct `String#contains` case.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!! I would likes to give +1 . But Sorry, I dont have enough reputation. Thanks a Lot :)

Comment: @EldhoNewAge You might want to accept the answer if it works for you.

Comment: But im having only 6 reputaions :(.This is my new account

Answer (score 2):

Java 8:

```
String all_vals  = "617,618,456,1,234,5,5678,225";
String check_val= "5678";
Arrays.stream(all_vals.split(",")).anyMatch(check_val:: equals)
if(Arrays.stream(all_vals.split(",")).anyMatch(check_val:: equals)){
    System.out.println("The value is present");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    String all_vals  = "617,618,456,1,234,5,5678,225";
    String check_val= "5678";
    int place = 1;

    String[] strings = all_vals.split(",");
    for (String str : strings) {
        if(str.equals(check_val))
        {
            System.out.println("We have string in all_val on place: " + place);
        }
        place++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String all_vals  = "617,618,456,1,234,5,5678,225";  
String check_val= "456";

if (all_vals.startsWith(check_val) || 
    all_vals.endsWith(check_val) || 
    all_vals.contains("," + check_val + ","))
{
    System.out.println("value found in string");
}
```

Comment: Why do you check the commas only in the `contains` case? Shouldn't be a comma before `check_val` at `endsWith` and one after `check_val` at `startsWich` ?

Comment: Would fail if `check_val= "25";`